# ogr2ogr spatial query doesn't work in process

Tags: postgresql, ogr2ogr

I tried exporting data selecting it from postgres with spatial query. The argument does work within osGeo4W Shell but I'm trying to use it from my C# console app. Everything seems too work until I add the spatial part. I have no idea what could be the issue here, but I'm still a beginner. Can someone take a look and help me figure out what went wrong here?

```cs
// assemble input
string output = "C:\\Users\\martijn\\Documents\\output.gpkg";
string connectionPostgis = " PG:\"dbname = db_naam host = localhost user = postgres password = password port = 5432 \" ";
string sqlRequest = "-sql \"SELECT naam, geom,ST_Distance(ST_GeographyFromText(\'POINT(4.9235515 52.3770089)\'),geom) FROM public.table \"";
string argument ="ogr2ogr -f \"GPKG\" " + output + connectionPostgis + sqlRequest;
            
// process
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\OSGeo4W.bat";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = argument;

process.Start();
```

Comment: did you try printing sqlRequest and argument to console? to check if the escaping is correct

Comment: and after printing the command, try to run it in the database directly, so you can see the error message

Comment: fist I tried the sqlRequest in pgAdmin 4v4 next in the command line. they seems to work without issue or error. (the comma was not the problem...)

Answer (score 0):

The point is invalid. Remove the coma between the longitude and the latitude

```
ST_GeographyFromText(\'POINT(4.9235515 52.3770089)\')
```